# Continuous TLS handshake error logs in vault nodes due to LB health check

Tags: ssl, tcp, load-balancing, hashicorp-vault, kubernetes-health-check

I am getting continuous TLS handshake errors every 5 sec due to my load balancer pinging vault nodes in every 5 seconds. Kube load balancer is pinging my vault nodes using

`nc -vz podip podPort` every 5 sec

I have already disabled client cert verification in my config.hcl but still see below logs in my kubectl logs for vault

```
kubectl logs pod-0 -n mynamespace 
[INFO]  http: TLS handshake error from 10.x.x.x:60056: EOF 2020-09-02T01:13:32.957Z 
[INFO]  http: TLS handshake error from 10.x.x.x:23995: EOF 2020-09-02T01:13:37.957Z 
[INFO]  http: TLS handshake error from 10.x.x.x:54165: EOF 2020-09-02T01:13:42.957Z
```

Below is my config.hcl which I am loading via kube config map

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: raft-config
  labels:
    name: raft-config
data:
  config.hcl: |
    storage "raft" {
      path  = "/vault-data"
      tls_skip_verify = "true"
      retry_join {
        leader_api_addr = "https://vault-cluster-0:8200"
        leader_ca_cert_file = "/opt/ca/vault.crt"
        leader_client_cert_file = "/opt/ca/vault.crt"
        leader_client_key_file = "/opt/ca/vault.key"
      }
      retry_join {
        leader_api_addr = "https://vault-cluster-1:8200"
        leader_ca_cert_file = "/opt/ca/vault.crt"
        leader_client_cert_file = "/opt/ca/vault.crt"
        leader_client_key_file = "/opt/ca/vault.key"
      }
      retry_join {
        leader_api_addr = "https://vault-cluster-2:8200"
        leader_ca_cert_file = "/opt/ca/vault.crt"
        leader_client_cert_file = "/opt/ca/vault.crt"
        leader_client_key_file = "/opt/ca/vault.key"
      }
    }
    seal "transit" {
     address = "https://vaulttransit:8200"
     disable_renewal = "false"
     key_name = "autounseal"
     mount_path = "transit/"
     tls_skip_verify = "true"
    }
    listener "tcp" {
     address = "0.0.0.0:8200"
     tls_cert_file = "/opt/ca/vault.crt"
     tls_key_file = "/opt/ca/vault.key"
     tls_skip_verify = "true"
     tls_disable_client_certs = "true"
    }
    ui=true
    disable_mlock = true
```

As I am using external open source vault image and my load balancer is an internal LB (which has internal CA cert). I am suspecting my vault pod is not able to recognize the CA cert provided by my load balancer when it tries to ping port 8200(TCP listener is started by vault on this port)

These logs are harmless and not causing any issue but they are unnecessary noise which I want to avoid. My vault nodes are working on https and there seems to be no issue in their functionality.

Can someone please help understand why vault TCP listener is trying to do TLS handshake even though I have explicitly specified `tls_disable_client_certs = "true"`

Again these logs are flooding my pods every 5 sec when my LB tries to do a health check on my pods using `nc -vz podip podPort`

My vault version is 1.5.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The messages are not about client certs or CA certs, a TLS handshake happens whether the client presents a certificate or not.

Instead, it is because a TCP connection is created and established and the Go library now wants to start a TLS handshake. Instead, the other side (the health checker) just hangs up and the TLS handshake never happens. Go then logs this message.

You are correct in saying that it is harmless, this is purely a side effect of port-liveness health checking. It is however spammy and annoying.

You have two basic options to get around this:

1. filter the messages out of the logs when persisting them
2. change to a different type of health check

I would recommend the second option: **switch to a different health check**. Vault has a [/sys/health](https://www.vaultproject.io/api-docs/system/health) endpoint that can be used with HTTPS health checks.

In addition to getting rid of the TLS warning messages, the health endpoint also allows to you check for active and unsealed nodes.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. unfortunately the disabling health checks is not an option for me as the load balancer is owned by a different team in my organization. Is there any way in vault itself to disable this noise?

Comment: No. And I never said to disable health checks, just to change the type of health check performed. Talk to the other team and have them change it, the `/sys/health` checks provide much better functionality and will make your vault deployment much more reliable.

Comment: I can move my health check to /sys/health using a readiness probe in my pod. but this would not stop the TCP health check as this is out of my control and is owned by other team and hence not stop the spamming. But atleast I know that its just noise and probably just ignore it.

Comment: This is a little frustrating because Hashicorp advises using an NLB in AWS for performance reasons which doesn't support layer 7 health check paths. We ended up just dropping these handshake errors in our fluent-bit config but it does make the local logs much harder to work with.